# Is there a point between 2 equal positive charges where the electric field is zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

I am having trouble with this question

Comment: Hello Morgan H and welcome to Physics SE. You should at least provide some information on what exactly is that presents some kind of difficulty to your understanding related to the question. Your question is quite vague. I suggest you edit it to add more information on what you have tried, what you have possibly read about it and what is that you don't understand. This way it will be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Electric field lines of two positive charges]

Yes, in-fact their is a whole plane. Assuming you know the basic difference between vectors and scalar, Electric field is a vector, so basically at that plane in the central region:

1. the vectors horizontal parts are equal and opposite and hence cancel each other.
2. The vertical components add up.

To think of it in an elementary way. The vectors, whenever they try to get close to each other, end up moving significantly more upwards(compared to their horizontal movement) the more close they are to the central plane.

I can add or edit the answer based on your understanding of vectors.